# For dynamically generated search input element, click on small "x" to clear fails to trigger using .on('search', function ()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a static and dynamically generated search input box. When I enter a value in the search box and click the "x" to clear it, I get a trigger for the static search box, but nothing happens with the dynamically generated one when I click on the "x".  Sample code below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="search_group" style="">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="search" class="form-control" id="search_text"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <h5 id="add_search" style="cursor:pointer">Dynamically ad Search Box</h5>
    
    <p id="append_here"></p>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        //this works on the static search box, but not on the dynamic search box
        $('input[type=search]').on('search', function () {
            console.log('X clicked');            
        });   
        
        //add search box dynamically
        $( "#add_search" ).on( "click", function() {
           var new_search_element = `<div id="search_group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="search" class="form-control" id="search_text"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>`;  
            $("#append_here").empty().append(new_search_element);
        });   
    </script    
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get the dynamically generated search box to respond to a click on the "x"?

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have to learn "Event Bubbling" 
Easy to Paste this link
https://bokboot.net/read?id=62&key=fdfd681c-1807-4e93-9ca4-b0f68a6717b5

```
$('#search_group').on('search', function (e) {
  if(e.target.id != "search_text") return;
  console.log('X clicked');            
  $("#data").empty();
});
```

Comment: Tried it, but did not work for me...

Comment: @HDer Can you upload your code on online code editor

Comment: I have updated the question to include simplified sample code representing the problem I am dealing with.